# Proof that if f is differentiable and g is differentiable, then f + g is differentiable (using linear approximation)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having some difficulty understanding a proof that $(f+g)$ is differentiable. We take $f$ and $g$ as differentiable and use a definition of differentiability:

> $f(x+v) - f(x) = L_x + \alpha(v)$ with $\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\alpha(v)}{||v||} = 0$
>
> $g(x+v) - g(x) = M_x + \beta(v) $ with $\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\beta(v)}{||v||} = 0$

Then we have:

> $(f+g)(x + v) - (f+g)(x) = f(x+v)+g(x+v)-f(x)-g(x)$

From the definitions:

> $= L_x(v) + \alpha(v) + M_x(v) + \beta(v)$
>
> $= (L_x + M_x)(v) + (\alpha + \beta)(v)$  **(1)**

We are also told that:

> $\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{(\alpha + \beta)(v)}{||v||} =  \lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\alpha(v) + \beta(v)}{||v||}$ **(2)**

I am not sure how to arrive at **(1)** and **(2)**. I thought it might relate to $L_x$ and $M_x$ being linear transformations, but I am not sure if this is a property. Would someone be able to help me out?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 1) and  2) are just the definitions of the sum of two functions: $(\alpha +\beta) (v)=\alpha (v)+\beta (v)$. Since sum of two linear transformations is linear 1) and 2) complete the proof of differentiability.

Comment: Thank you Kavi Rama. (2) was indeed very simple. Looking at it again, is there any reason why this doesn't apply to (1) as well to combine $L_x(v)$ and $M_x(v)$?

Comment: @Christian You are right. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By your step we have defined

$$(\alpha + \beta)(v):=\alpha(v)+ \beta(v)$$

then it follows that

$$\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{(\alpha + \beta)(v)}{||v||} =  \lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\alpha(v) + \beta(v)}{||v||}=\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\alpha(v)}{||v||}+\lim\limits_{v \to 0} \frac{\beta(v)}{||v||}=0+0=0$$

Comment: Thank you Gimusi. My question turned out to be a little more simple, but the additional steps here are useful.

Comment: Yes the key point is that that the differential is linear and then the sum is again linear and for the remainder linearity of limits suffices to conclude. More interesting is the case of composition $f\circ g$.